# Is it possible to bind `C-u C-x C-x`s behavior into `C-x C-x`

Tags: key-bindings

I have adviced to use `C-u C-x C-x` to jump back to latest position I jumped before. For example, if I do `M-<` and `C-u C-x C-x`, first I jump beginning of the file and come back to point I jumped.

When I do `C-x C-x` it does the same operation and also marks it. Since I don't need to mark it, is it possible to obtain `C-u C-x C-x`s behavior, when I press `C-x C-x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better advice would have been to use `C-u C-SPC` to return to where the mark has been set. Using `C-u C-x C-x` to return to where the mark has been set runs the function `exchange-point-and-mark` which puts the mark where point used to be which is probably not what you wanted.

If you still want what you asked for here it is:

```
(defun alt-exchange-point-and-mark (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (exchange-point-and-mark (not arg)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-x") 'alt-exchange-point-and-mark)
```

Comment: When `alt-exchange-point-and-mark` is perform, when we jump to line, can the jumped line be on the center of the frame? @Aidan Schofield

Comment: `C-l` will put the line that the point is in at the centre of the window. It runs the command `recenter-top-bottom` so you could throw that into the definition of `alt-exchange-point-and-mark` at the end if you wish.

Comment: Sorry for late comment, right after `M-<` if I make paste, it won't get back to point I jumped instead it jumps back to starting location of where paste happens