# How to move point to the vertical center of the window when I use `C-u C-SPC`?

Tags: window

I am using following [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59194/18414) to jump to the previous jumped point and I also use `C-u C-SPC` as well.

> ```
> (defun alt-exchange-point-and-mark (&optional arg)   
>     (interactive"P")   
>     (exchange-point-and-mark (not arg)))
>
> (global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-x") 'alt-exchange-point-and-mark)
> ```

**[Q]** When the jump operation is performend, can the jumped line be on the center of the window?

Comment: Add `(recenter)` to the function?

Comment: Should I add it right after `(interactive"P") `?

Comment: No, it should be the last thing: try it interactively first: Do `C-x C-x` to do the exchange and then `C-l` to do the recenter. Or try it the other way first and see. And do `C-h c C-l` to check the binding and `C-h f recenter RET` to check the function.