# Is it possible to ignore paste operation during `C-x C-x` to jump back?

Tags: key-bindings, motion

This question is related to [Is it possible to bind `C-u C-x C-x`s behavior into `C-x C-x`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59193/is-it-possible-to-bind-c-u-c-x-c-xs-behavior-into-c-x-c-x). My main goal is to jump top of the file, type `import`  and paste a package name and jump back where I was.

**Scenario:**

I am on the line 10 and copied a word. Than I press `M-<`to jump top of the file, move down to line 1 and typed `import`  and pasted the copied word. Now when I press `C-x C-x`, it jumps to the starting point of the pasted word and if I press again it jumps to end of the paster word in the line 1.

```
0                                     | <= jumped here and go one line below
1                                     | import hello_world  # (2) type import and 
2                                     |                       paste hello_world \
3                                     |                                         |
4                                     |                                         |
5                                     |                                         |
6                                     |                                         |
7                                     |                                         |                        
8                                     |                                         |
9                                     |                                         |
10 hello_world()  # (1)cursor is here | <= (3) I want to jump back here <--------
```

At this point, I just want to jump pack to point where I was (which is line 10), how can I acheive it?

Comment: as you are not intending to operate on what it should be a region, I'd encapsulate the functionality in a custom command just saving the position to get back to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each command that sets the mark pushes the previous mark onto a stack. More precisely, the previous position is added to the [mark ring](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark-Ring.html#Mark-Ring) (the difference between a mark and a ring is that accessing the front of the ring doesn't remove the element, but pushes it to the other side of the ring).

To get to the next-to-last position, use `C-1 C-SPC` or `C-u C-SPC`. Repeat to get to the previous position, etc. Or use directly `C-2 C-SPC` to go two positions back, and so on. `C-SPC` (`set-mark-command`) is the command to set the mark, but with a numeric argument or a `C-u` prefix, it jumps back to a previous mark instead of setting the mark.

In your case, both `M-<` and pasting set a mark, so you want to go two marks back, hence `C-2 C-SPC` or `C-u C-SPC C-u C-SPC`.

If Emacs is running in a terminal, you may need to use `C-u 2` or `M-2` or `ESC 2` instead of `C-2`.

Comment: One thing I've found difficult with rings is reusing an item frequently as they are moving targets. Registers worked better to me in such scenario.

Answer (score 3):

As you're not going to use the region between point and mark, consider another approach using `save-excursion`, like this one:

```lisp
(defun auto-import-word-at-point()
    "Autoimport word at point."
    (interactive)
    (let ((word-at-point (thing-at-point 'word)))
        (save-excursion
            (goto-line 2)
            (insert (concat "import " word-at-point))
            (newline))))
```

It will copy the thing at point, goto line 2, insert it there and restore things. Bind to whatever you want and it's ready to go, `thing-at-point` is just a way to obtain data, but can use anything else that you may prefer.

`thing-at-point` will automagically get the specified kind of thing around point; as `save-excursion` will save point, it'll return to it after executing its body, but saved point may not be the end of word, so you may want to `forward-word` (`M-f`) which was left out for clarity.

Comment: This is smart, another issue is some times I need to go to top of the page and see the other imports to remember, if I have to use `from <import_name> import <module>`. That will be helpful if top 15 lines that has all imports could be seen in the mini-buffer incase to let us remember the which from <import_name> we will be using

Comment: as first approach I'd `clone-indirect-buffer`, move to the top and will wait for some kind of user input, will have more screen state than minibuffer.